Kwikset exterior deadbolt thumb turn set screw
Kwikset deadbolt has an interior thumb turn knob that is held on by a single small set screw. To be clear, I’m not talking about the long assembly screws that attach to the exterior cylinder to the interior thumb turn assembly. The single set screw came out and I can’t find it. Consequently the thumb turn knob came off. It’s apparently an unusual turn knob assembly. Most don’t have a set screw. I purchased it in 2010. This style deadbolt assembly doesn’t appear on Kwikset website parts section. Any suggestions on what size set screw and where to buy?

Take the thumb knob to local hardware/plumbing/electrical/garage/auto parts store.  I guess the size from 1/8 to 1/4 inch.

Go digging in your garage  and find 8/32 or 10/32 screws and see if they fit. Then buy the set screw at proper lenght

There’s also a chance that it’s a rolled friction pin… again, your local hardware store will help.

I think that the set screw (hex screw) is similar to the one in the handle. That’s something like a 5/32. I would upload a pic of the thumb turn knob, but I don’t know how to do that. The length is short, maybe 3/16”, possibly less?

I don't think we can tell from a pic.  If you're near civilization, take it somewhere per @crip659.  Or does the screw thread into the shaft itself, making it more difficult to take to the store?  BTW, if this was a recurrent problem before the screw was lost for good, consider picking up some low-strength thread sealant; or dab the threads with nail polish before you install the new screw.

The length does not matter as much as the diameter.  Unless you get one long enough to rip the skin of your finger when turning.  Unlikely since set screws are short.

It’s strange that I purchased 5 Kwikset Exterior Door sets at the same time, which I thought they were identical, but the thumb turn handle on one set uses a hex screw to attach the handle. It should be a very minor issue. I appreciate the replies. I took the knob to a locksmith. A quick resolve. But I’m a little disappointed that I couldn’t get factory parts.

I have a Kwikset deadbolt where the thumb knob came off and the set screw was lost.  For me, the replacement set screw was #6-32 x 1/8" .  If you can't find this, then #6-32 x 3/16" would work with just a small part of the screw sticking out of the non-functional knob area.  Bought at Home Depot, these set screws need a 1/16" hex key.
